# Java CSVParser breaklines

Tags: java, csv

How can I deal with breaklines in column in CSVParser for Java.

```
Reader in = new FileReader(csvFile);
csvParser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withQuote('"').withDelimiter(';').withEscape('\\').withRecordSeparator('\n').parse(in);
columnList = csvParser.getHeaderNames();

for(CSVRecord record: csvParser.getRecords()) {
  rows.add(prepareRow(record));
}
```

Here is my options, but when I have something like this I can't run it, because it ignore " " as escape

```
1042377;"Test";"Test";Test;611945;311.12;2;https://example.com/1.jpg;"&#13;
&#13;
&#13;
&#13;
&#13;"
1042377;"Test";"Test";Test;611945;311.12;2;https://example.com/2.jpg;"&#13;
&#13;
&#13;
&#13;
&#13;"
```

it should create 2 rows, but it create more rows. How can I fix it? Edit for send code

it works fine when I don't have strings which have only 1 line, but it's problematic when I have string with multiple rows

Comment: Please share the code where you parse the CSV. Also, are you sure the quotes are " and not other weird quotes like ”?

Comment: @Eduard edited code and change example  for more realistic

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your issue, the parser seems to be working fine. This code:

```
CSVParser csvParser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
//      .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
        .withQuote('"')
        .withDelimiter(';')
        .withEscape('\\')
        .withRecordSeparator('\n')
        .parse(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(in.getBytes())));
for(CSVRecord record: csvParser.getRecords()){
    //replace new line char with a visible "\n"
    record.forEach(field -> System.out.println(field.replace("\n", "\\n")));
    System.out.println("End of record.");
}
```

Prints this output:

```
1042377
Test
Test
Test
611945
311.12
2
https://example.com/1.jpg
&#13;\n&#13;\n&#13;\n&#13;\n&#13;
End of record.
1042377
Test
Test
Test
611945
311.12
2
https://example.com/2.jpg
&#13;\n&#13;\n&#13;\n&#13;\n&#13;
End of record.
```

As you can see, it parses 2 rows with 9 columns each.

I am working with version 1.7 of org.apache.commons:commons-csv.

Note: I've commented `.withFirstRecordAsHeader()` because you don't have headers.

Answer (score 0):

I found problem. It was, because I had \" in my data. I'm not sure, but I couldn't fix it. I changed it in csv file